# Sum over multiindex pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to create a dataframe, where both columns (years, quarters, month) and indices (some attributes) are hierarchical, i.e. multiindex. I would like to sum over some levels, for example sum over all month belonging to a quarter. In pandas one can do something like this by e.g. the following line:

```
# Axis 1 = columns, level 0 = year, level 1 = quarter
df.sum(axis=1, level=[0, 1]
```

This worked until in some strange cases the indices where not correctly identified any more, triggering the error message `No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

In the following code I create two identical dataframes (multiindex in both axes), with only one difference: `df1` is not filled when created, `df2` is directly filled when created with ones. Summation does work with `df2`, but not with `df1`. I do not understand, what happened in the background, can someone please point me to a solution to understand this difference?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = [(y, divmod(m - 1, 3)[0] + 1, m)
        for y in list(range(2011, 2014)) for m in list(range(1, 13))]

inds = [(a, b, c)
        for a in ["a1", "a2"] for b in ["b1", "b2"] for c in ["c1", "c2"]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(inds, names=["a", "b", "c"]),
                   columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols, names=["year", "quarter", "month"]))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(df1.shape),
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(inds, names=["a", "b", "c"]),
                   columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols, names=["year", "quarter", "month"]))

for (col, ind) in [(col, ind) for ind in df1.index.values for col in df1.columns.values]:
    entry = np.random.rand()
    df1.loc[ind, col] = entry
    df2.loc[ind, col] = entry

try:
    df1.sum(axis=1, level=[0, 1])
    print("Sum over df1 did work")
except:
    print("Sum over df1 did not work...")

try:
    df2.sum(axis=1, level=[0, 1])
    print("Sum over df2 did work")
except:
    print("Sum over df2 did not work...")
```

PS: found some hint, the type of the entries in `df1` is `float`, in `df2` it is `np.float64`, but this still does not help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem all values in `df1` are `object`s, what is obviously `string`s, but here it is `<class 'float'>`:

```
print (df1.dtypes)
year  quarter  month
2011  1        1        object
               2        object
               3        object
      2        4        object
               5        object
               6        object
      3        7        object
               8        object
               9        object
      4        10       object

print (df2.dtypes)
year  quarter  month
2011  1        1        float64
               2        float64
               3        float64
      2        4        float64
               5        float64
               6        float64
      3        7        float64
               8        float64
```

So casting works:

```
try:
    df1.astype(float).sum(axis=1, level=[0, 1])
    print("Sum over df1 did work")
except:
    print("Sum over df1 did not work...")

try:
    df2.sum(axis=1, level=[0, 1])
    print("Sum over df2 did work")
except:
    print("Sum over df2 did not work...")
Sum over df1 did work
Sum over df2 did work
```

---

```
for (col, ind) in [(col, ind) for ind in df1.index.values for col in df1.columns.values]:
    entry = np.random.rand()
    df1.loc[ind, col] = entry
    print (type(df1.loc[ind, col]))
    df2.loc[ind, col] = entry
    print (type(df2.loc[ind, col]))

<class 'float'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

The best is create `DataFrame` by numpy array, then all works nice:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(len(inds), len(cols)),
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(inds, names=["a", "b", "c"]),
                   columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols, names=["year","quarter","month"]))


try:
    df1.sum(axis=1, level=[0, 1])
    print("Sum over df1 did work")
except:
    print("Sum over df1 did not work...")
Sum over df1 did work
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! However, instead of filling the dataframe also adding `pd.DataFrame(dtype=np.float64 ...` did the job (especially since I expect quite some `np.nan`entries)

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!